# Having exit status 1 on react compilation with nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hi im having this error and i have no idea why it is... i did a lot of research but didnt find what i need.

I have next js and the script for npm run build is like this "next build"

and this issue is happening now over and over again.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.10.0
3 info using node@v12.7.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~prebuild: start-p@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: start-p@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Rion\Desktop\InvisReact\invis\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Rion\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Rion\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\Rion\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Rion\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Rion\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Rion\Desktop\InvisReact\invis
10 silly lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle start-p@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: start-p@1.0.0 build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid start-p@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Rion\Desktop\InvisReact\invis
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.7.0
19 verbose npm  v6.10.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error start-p@1.0.0 build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the start-p@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?